# How can I center a full width Bootstrap 3 tool-tip

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have multiple `tooltips` on my web page that are quite long, so I made the tooltip `width 80%` instead of the default `200px`.

Right now the tooltip is flushed completely to the left, and **I want it to sit in the center of the page just like content in the .container div does**.

This works fine, however the tooltip is to the left with a large gap to the right.

I tried adding margin to the left of the tooltip div with no luck, and I also tried to wrap the tooltip div (in jQuery) with a container.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.tooltip').wrap('<div class="container"></div>');
});
```

```css
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 100%!important;
  /* If max-width does not work, try using width instead */
  width: 80%!important;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 15%!important;
  display: inline-block!important;
}

.tooltip.top {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" style="color:#6D6E71;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip text">
        hover over me
    </a>
```

But that also didn't work. Has anyone had any luck getting the tooltip to center as opposed to being flushed to the left side of the screen?

Comment: @user2596635 can you please share your expectations in more details? AS of now tooltip is showing properly against mouse position. May be you could put your real HTML and rest of the code?

Comment: That is my real HTML aside from the tooltip title being a paragraph. Right now the tooltip is flushed completely to the left, and I want it to sit in the center of the page just like content in the .container div does, thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your desired style but you can put any HTML in a tooltip - just be sure to use single quotes inside.  Couple of examples:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container tooltip-container">
  <a href="#" style="color:#6D6E71;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom tooltip text">hover over me</a>
</div>
<div class="container ">
  <div class="row col-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" title="<div class='col-8 alert alert-info'><div class='col-8'>Tooltip</div> <div>I have a lot of text.  I am the fun guy text. Tip me with cash please.</div><b>HTML inside</b></div>">
      Tooltip with HTML
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```